# keyvault network_acl apply if condition true else allow all networks

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

1. I have 4 environments : DEV/SIT/PRE/PRD
2. Using same code to create keyvault in all 4 environments by just passing environment name as variable to differentiate in names.
3. only network_acl present in code. I want network_acl to apply only if environment is PRE or PRD. In case of DEV or SIT it should allow all networks.

```
    resource "azurerm_key_vault" "mykeyvault" {
      name                = lower(format("%s-%s", var.environment_name, "key"))

    access policy {
      tenant_id = var.tenant_id
      object_id = var.object_id
      secret_permission = ["Get"]
     }

    var.environment_instance == "PRE" || var.environment_instance == "PRD" ?
    network_acls {
        default_action              = "Deny"
        bypass                      = "AzureServices"
        ip_rules                    =  ["1.2.3.4/5"]
     }
    :
    network_acls {
        default_action              = "Allow"
        bypass                      = "AzureServices"
    }
    }
```

I want a condition which will work something related to how i have tried from my end. Mine did not worked as expected, it failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    network_acls {
        default_action              = var.environment_instance == "PRE" || var.environment_instance == "PRD" ? "Deny" : "Allow"
        bypass                      = "AzureServices"
        ip_rules                    =  ["1.2.3.4/5"]
    }
```